# Ports necessary for Oracle 11g Replication across a firewall?

Tags: oracle, replication, oracle-11g-r2, windows, network

We have two Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition servers that need to replicate data via Oracle streams.  However, the two servers are on untrusted domains and connect via a VPN.  On end of the connection is a Juniper firewall, with the other side a TMG firewall.

I know the listener runs on port 1521, but what other ports or port ranges should be opened for Oracle replication to work correctly?

Comment: Oracle's network protocol uses more than just port 1521: port 1521 is used purely for the initial connection. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6246318/391445 for more information.

Comment: Are you sure? The client will use a whole range of ports to connect to the listener port, but i was under the impression Oracle only listens on port 1521. Of course, this could be part of the problem, if the outgoing client connections get blocked.

Comment: Yes, if I recall correctly: the server process connects back to the client on a port number that the client communicates to the server as part of the connection process.

Comment: I was wrong in the details. In some implementations the listener communicates the new port number of the server process that has been started for the client and the client connects to that. But some newer versions don't do this anymore. Rather than regurgitate everything, here's a useful link that also includes references to Firewall vendors' docs: http://packetpushers.net/sqlnet-a-k-a-oracle-tns-and-firewalls/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any other ports than the listener ports are required.
I suspect that the ports need to be open on your source AND target database/firewall, allowing both incoming and outgoing connections. Also, the host running RMAN has to be able to reach the listener ports, but that's probably default.

If tnsping works to both servers from the host you are running RMAN from, i think you should be all set.